# Managing file descriptors in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh, io-redirection

I am having some troubles programming my shell to execute file IO redirection correctly.  It is under my impression that this is how the algorithm goes.

Given a command: `cat file > newfile`

My sh does as follows:

1) Parse the command into 2 parts, `cat file` and `newfile`

2) `fd = open(newfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT) // This opens the newfile for write or creates the file if it does not exist.`

3) `close(0) // close stdout`

4) `dup(fd) // this should copy the file descriptor for newfile into stdout since stdout is available`

From here, I thought I was done and all output to fd 0 (eg. printfs(), write(0, buf, 64), etc) would go into my newfile. However, as soon as I do this my program loops the error 'fd 0 is not open for READ' which seems correct because 0 should be my file which is NOT read. Not sure what is attempting to READ from 0 though.

Is this logic correct or am I just missing something? Thanks

Comment: [stdout is fd 1.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html)

Comment: In addition to @nemo's comment, it's probably better to be explicit:  `dup2(fd, 1)`, which closes the existing file descriptor at 1 first for you.

Comment: ok thanks guys. I totally mixed up stdout and stdin

Comment: Use the #defines given in the system headers: STDOUT_FILENO and STDIN_FILENO

Answer (score 2):

> 3) `close(0) // close stdout`

But `0` is really `stdin`.  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/unistd.h.html) states that in `<unistd.h>`

```
The following symbolic constants shall be defined for file streams:

STDERR_FILENO
    File number of stderr; 2.
STDIN_FILENO
    File number of stdin; 0.
STDOUT_FILENO
    File number of stdout; 1.
```

You could use these symbolic constants to avoid similar errors.